# Optimize Django query in reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have **2 models**

```
class Chassis(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

class Eir(models.Model):
    chassis = models.ForeignKey(
        'management.Chassis',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='eir',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=0)
```

I tested via Django CLI

```
>>> chassis = Chassis.objects.prefetch_related('eir')
>>> chassis
>>> chassis.first().eir.all()
```

I tried the commands above and it still did a query with the `eir` table as shown below:

```
# produced from ">>> chassis"
{"Time":[2023-03-07 08:25:42 UTC], Host:10.116.1.165} LOG:  duration: 0.238 ms  statement: SELECT "management_chassis"."id", "management_chassis"."number" FROM "management_chassis" LIMIT 21
{"Time":[2023-03-07 08:25:42 UTC], Host:10.116.1.165} LOG:  duration: 0.777 ms  statement: SELECT "rental_eir"."id", "rental_eir"."number", "rental_eir"."chassis_id" FROM "rental_eir" WHERE "rental_eir"."chassis_id" IN (1292, 104)

# produced from ">>> chassis.first().eir.all()"
{"Time":[2023-03-07 08:25:59 UTC], Host:10.116.1.165} LOG:  duration: 0.239 ms  statement: SELECT "rental_eir"."id", "rental_eir"."number", "rental_eir"."chassis_id" FROM "rental_eir" WHERE "rental_eir"."chassis_id" IN (1292)
```

I was expecting that there will be no 3rd query anymore as the data will be stored in memory.
My real purpose is related to Django REST Framework manipulating the returned data in `def to_representation` where a reverse lookup is done like `ret['eir'] = instance.eir.all().last().id` where `instance` is `Chassis` model.

Generally, I am trying to reduce unnecessaty queries produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.first()` does not read the cache.
If you want to reduce the number of queries you'll need to cast the queryset in a list.
However if you don't need the entire "chassis" list, `chassis.first().eir.all()` result in leaner queries (tanks to the `limit 1`).

```
>>> chassis = list(Chassis.objects.prefetch_related('eir'))
>>> chassis
>>> chassis[0].eir.all()
```

However, this a bit different compared to the usecase you described with the serializer.
Replacing `ret['eir'] = instance.eir.all().last().id` by `ret['eir'] = instance.eir.all()[-1].id` should produce minimal queries if "eir" is prefetch

Comment: Can you give an example by code? I tried `chassis[0]` and it still produced an additional query

Comment: Sorry, i wrote a new, hopefully clearer, answer

Comment: Wow, this actually did the trick. Except `[-1]` is not possible for queryset